# Flexbox "nowrap" value isn't working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

This is the section of my code that doesn't work:

```css
.copyright {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /* This is not working */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p>Sample</p>
<span>
  <li class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#3b5998"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aced"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </li>
</span>
<br><br>
<p class="copyright">
  <span>I want this left from icons</span>
  <span>
   <li class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#3b5998"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
   </li>
   <li class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aced"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
   </li>
  </span>
</p>
```

Do you know why `flexwrap: nowrap;` isn't working? My icons are below the span instead of being placed to the right.

Comment: This HTML structure is craziness

Comment: This html code has multiple problems. While most browsers tolerate bad html, there is no way of knowing how they will interpret it. In this instance, <li>...</li> ends up being *outside* of <p class="copyright"> in the understanding of Firefox (it just closed <p> when it saw <li>. Some of the issues: <li> can't be within <p> and it can't be within <span>, either. There should be <ul> or <ol> around <li>. It is always best to run your code through an HTML validator before deciding it is 'not working' or attempting to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your copyright class `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 15):

It's not working because `flex-wrap: nowrap` applies to flex items, not the text inside the item. You need to target the text with `white-space: nowrap`.

```
.copyright {
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;   /* will prevent flex items on the same line from wrapping */
     white-space: nowrap; /* will prevent text from wrapping */
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vw9t2y/51/)

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update `<p class="copyright">` with `<div class="copyright">`

Or I could use `display:block` for the `p.copyright`

Answer (score 0):

Just need a common wrapper such a div and display flex

```css
div {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p>Sample</p>
<span>
 <li class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#3b5998"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
 </li>
 <li class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aced"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
 </li>
</span>
<br><br>
<p class="copyright">
  <div>
    <span>I want this left from icons</span>
    <span>
 <li class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#3b5998"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
 </li>
 <li class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aced"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
 </li>
</span>
  </div>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

which ever elements or icons you want to see in a line and in order, then place those in a div element which is having flex.
and you dont need flex-wrap property as with proper html order ,just a display:flex property will take care of most of the things

See here https://jsfiddle.net/b6vw9t2y/38/
    `<div style='display: flex'>
      <i>icon1></i>
      <i>icon2</i>
      <i>icon3</i>
 </div>`

**output**: icon1 icon2 icon3

go through below link for flexbox basics , its understandable and it will surely makes ur life much easier when u get the grip of flexbox

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp